# System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. while working with a word document to edit via c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I was trying to do a Word Document Editor in c# with the main idea of changing certain fields in a word document. Like for example where the word  **name**, to replace with an actual name that I type in a windows form field. Think of it as a Certificate generator. where i just need to change the Date and name.

But i keep getting an error where the Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The error im getting is on  `Word.Range nom = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref name1).Range;`

here is the complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

  namespace WindowsFormsApp5
  {
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object ObjMiss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Word.Application ObjWord = new Word.Application();
        string route = Application.StartupPath + @"C:\document.docx";
        object parametro = route;
        object name1 = "name";
        object telephone1 = "telephone";

        
        
        
        Word.Document ObjDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open(parametro , ObjMiss);
        
        Word.Range nom = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref name1).Range;
        nam.Text = textBox1.Text;
        Word.Range tel = ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref telephone1).Range;
        tel.Text = textBox2.Text;
        object rango1 = nam;
         object range2 = tel;
         ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("name", ref range1);
         ObjDoc.Bookmarks.Add("telephone", ref range2);
        ObjWord.Visible = true;

    }
  }
}
```

I am completely sure I have the correct route the word document, I also inserted the bookmarks necesary in the place I want to replace the words.

Comment: did you figure out which object in the call hierarchy is the one returning null ?`ObjDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref name1).Range` - ObjDoc, Bookmarks, get_item(ref name1) or Range ?

Comment: ObjDoc is returning null

Comment: If you are not able to produce a single scenario where you are able to get a valid ObjDoc, then you must be sending an incorrect parameter value to `Word.Document ObjDoc = ObjWord.Documents.Open(parametro , ObjMiss);`. Why do you not try getting the path using a `FileOpenDialog.FileName` ? This way you make sure you are making no mistakes with the path.

Comment: `Application.StartupPath + @"C:\document.docx";` will never produce a valid path. `C:\document.docx` is an absolute path, trying to load a file named `document.docx` stored in the root folder of the `C:` drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that

```cs
Application.StartupPath + @"C:\document.docx";
```

yelds the intended path? It would be something like

```
"C:\path\to\application\C:\document.docx"
```

As far as I know, " **:** " is not even an accepted character for folder names.

Comment: string route = Application.StartupPath + @"C:\Users\name\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp5\WindowsFormsApp5\document.docx";     this is my full path and im pretty sure it works because i tried switching the path, but i get a different error which is that the document is not found or missing.

Comment: If that's the path, you should remove the ```C:\``` before ```document.docx```, otherwise you will have the wrong path I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @alexschobel it doesn't work. The only way this could ever work would be for `Application.StartupPath` to be an empty string. This isn't a matter of opinion. Did you actually try debugging your code and inspecting what `route` contains?

Comment: @alexschobel use `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation. If `StartupPath` ends in a backslash you'll still end up with an invalid path

Comment: okay, yes I understand i removed the C: and i left it as @"/document.docx , after that I noticed that also my document.docx is not supposed to be inside that folder but inside the debug folder of the proyect for it to work. so thank you for the comment and answers.

Comment: To be clear, ```Application.StartupPath``` will return a string in the form ```C:\path\to\app```, and you are combining that with ```C:\document.docx```. The resulting string is not a valid path for sure. The fact that your object is null is a hint that this could really be the problem.